# Firestore whereIn query documents are randomly ordered

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of groups and a collection of users, each user document has a collection of ids to the group he has joined. each group id document has one field (timestamp) to mark when a user joined a group.
I want to get the list of groups the user has joined in ordered by timestamp descending.
First I am getting the groups ids from the sub collection inside user document and they are ordered by timestamp, Then, I am using whereIn() to get the groups objects from the groups top level collection by passing 'groupsIds' ArrayList.

Here is the problem, resulted documents from whereIn() are randomly ordered. I want them to be ordered according to 'groupsIds' list. Can firestore do that for me ? Or I will have to do this myself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't tell Firestore how to sort the documents using `orderBy`, you're going to have to sort the documents yourself.  And in this case, you are going to have to do that.

Comment: Well, wouldn't be a nice feature if documents returned using whereIn() are ordered according to their presence in the array passed, I mean that's how I thought It would do

Comment: If you have a feature request, feel free to file it with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support